# Simple query taking very long time

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, amazon-rds

I am running a relatively simple query on a postgres database:

```
 INSERT INTO tt (pid, trip_pid) SELECT stop_time.pid, trip.pid                                 
 FROM stop_time, trip                                                                          
 WHERE stop_time.trip_id = trip.trip_id AND 
 17 = trip.gtfsfeed_id 
 AND 17 = stop_time.gtfsfeed_id
```

tt is a temporary table, stop_time contains around 2 million rows, and trip  contains only around 50,000. This query has been running for over an hour on my aws rds instance, and I am not sure why. Is there something woefully inefficient about this query?

Edit: Here is the EXPLAIN (I created a new temporary table with the same columns to run explain)

```
                                   QUERY PLAN                                   
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Insert on ll  (cost=2604.38..75394.65 rows=1649975 width=8)
   ->  Hash Join  (cost=2604.38..75394.65 rows=1649975 width=8)
         Hash Cond: ((stop_time.trip_id)::text = (trip.trip_id)::text)
         ->  Seq Scan on stop_time  (cost=0.00..49406.68 rows=1835694 width=34)
               Filter: (gtfsfeed_id = 17)
         ->  Hash  (cost=2123.74..2123.74 rows=38451 width=34)
               ->  Seq Scan on trip  (cost=0.00..2123.74 rows=38451 width=34)
                     Filter: (gtfsfeed_id = 17)
```

Comment: Can you show us the `EXPLAIN PLAN` for the query?

Comment: I have added it

Comment: Try bulk insert with forall statement.

Comment: @Avi I dont think there is a forall in postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequential scans on your `trip` and `stop_time` tables suggest that they are not indexed on the `trip_id` fields. Adding a `trip_id` index to both tables would dramatically improve the `JOIN`.

Also, adding an index on `gtfsfeed_id` in both tables would make the query faster since your query is limiting results to specific values of those fields.

**Tip:** It's often useful to add an index of fields used in `JOIN` and `WHERE` statements.

Answer (score 1):

Check this query, mayby will faster

```
INSERT INTO tt (pid, trip_pid) 
SELECT stop_time.pid, trip.pid                                 
FROM stop_time st
join trip t on t.trip_id = st.trip_id
where t.gtfsfeed_id = 17
and st.gtfsfeed_id = 17;
```

And you can add index for columns `gtfsfeed_id`

Answer (score 1):

See that the table statistics are accurate and try indexes on `stop_time(gtfsfeed_id)` and/or `trip(gtfsfeed_id)`.